# DynamoDb Batch write update

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

When we do `table.batch_writer()` , the boto3 API , does it insert or it updates as well?

By Update i mean the `partition key`, `sort key are same` , but other `attributes` are not same.I cannot find this in any documentation.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `batch_writer` in [Boto3](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/dynamodb.html#batch-writing) maps to the [Batch Writing functionality](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html) offered by DynamoDB, as a service. This Batch Writing refers specifically to PutItem and DeleteItem operations and it does not include UpdateItem.

*From the docs*:

> The BatchWriteItem operation puts or deletes multiple items in one or more tables. A single call to BatchWriteItem can write up to 16 MB of data, which can comprise as many as 25 put or delete requests. Individual items to be written can be as large as 400 KB.
>
> > **Note**
> >
> > BatchWriteItem cannot update items. To update items, use the UpdateItem action.

To be clear, the [PutItem operation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_PutItem.html) either inserts a new item or replaces an item, uniquely identified by its key (either partition-only, or composite partition+sort key based on how the table was defined). So in a way, you may think of replacing an item as *updating* it's non-key attributes but it's more correct to think of that as a replace rather than an update. Contrast this with the [UpdateItem API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html) which allows selective manipulation of an item's attributes.

It's worth mentioning that even with Put & Delete item functions, the batch API is more limiting than doing individual PutItem or DeleteItem calls because it doesn't support conditional writes. The BatchWrite API is really only useful for batch loading, or batch deleting of data to save on network overhead with respect to HTTP headers, additional compute resources to generate & verify SigV4 signature, etc.

Comment: Question about when to use `batch_write` vs `put Item`.   
Considering the fact that sometimes I habe multiple items to write and sometimes a single item, should it be a good practiceto move to write via batch writing for both usecases? Or do we have pitfalls in cost or other issues?

Comment: Batching a single item doesn’t make a lot of sense and would definitely not be something you should do on purpose. Batching a single item doesn’t cost extra and performance m-wise it should be about the same as a singleton write despite a likely small overhead server-side but the batch api is more restrictive. In the end, make sure to instrument your app and measure for yourself.

Comment: Thanks, but I mean should I go in approach of `if else`. Meaning if I have single item or less then 16MB then go for `put item` , else for `batch write`, or maybe more reasonable to always do batch write in such case :) - without conditions